# Does anybody know what this C++ inline assembly does?

Tags: c++, assembly, inline-assembly

I've seen the following code in an open source windows tool called [DM2](http://sourceforge.net/p/dm2/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/dm2/global.h).

```
#define OEP_ASM __asm jmp OEP \
__asm _emit 0x5B __asm _emit 0x66 __asm _emit 0x6C \
__asm _emit 0x79 __asm _emit 0x66 __asm _emit 0x61 \
__asm _emit 0x6E __asm _emit 0x63 __asm _emit 0x79 \
__asm _emit 0x26 __asm _emit 0x57 __asm _emit 0x65 \
__asm _emit 0x69 __asm _emit 0x72 __asm _emit 0x64 \
__asm _emit 0x5D __asm _emit 0x00 __asm OEP:
```

There are no comments and searching the internet I sill haven't understood what this does?! [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1b80826t.aspx) just tells me that this inserts bytes into the code. This much I understand but I don't understand what these bytes do, it doesn't look like instructions.

Can anybody explain, or at least point me in the right direction what inserting bytes actually does?

Comment: You might want to check the generated code to see what instructions those are. Or read an Intel reference sheet.

Comment: what do you mean by checking the generated code?

Comment: Compile it, and check the actual code in the object file. Then at least you can see the actual instructions instead of just hex numbers. *How* to do it depend on the compiler you use. For Linux/OSX you can use e.g. the [`od` command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/od). On Windows with Visual Studio it probably have its own program do load object files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Indeed this is not code, it's just a string. Probably emitted like this for obfuscation purposes.

```
$ echo $'\x5B\x66\x6C\x79\x66\x61\x6E\x63\x79\x26\x57\x65\x69\x72\x64\x5D'
[flyfancy&Weird]
```

Or maybe it has to be embedded into the code section and inline asm doesn't provide a way to do that otherwise. Also notice that the first instruction jumps over the entire string.

Comment: got it...guess it's kind of a graffiti tag, nice. Confused me for a while :-)

Answer (score 3):

It's just a null-terminated ASCII string `[flyfancy&Weird]` embedded into the code (as the comment suggests). The `jmp OEP` instruction jumps over that string.